# How to extract all comma delimited numbers inside () bracked and ignore any text

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the comma delimited numbers inside () brackets from a string. I can get the numbers if that are alone in a line. But i cant seem to find a solution to get the numbers when other surrounding text is involved. Any help will be appreciated. Below is the code that I current use in python.

```
 line = """
Abuta has a history of use in the preparation of curares, an arrow poison to cause asphyxiation in hunting
It has also been used in traditional South American and Indian Ayurvedic medicines (101065,101066,101067)
The genus name Cissampelos is derived from the Greek words for ivy and vine (101065)
"""
 line = each.strip()
         regex_criteria = r'"^([1-9][0-9]*|\([1-9][0-9]*\}|\(([1-9][0-9]*,?)+[1-9][0-9]*\))$"gm'
         if (line.__contains__('(') and line.__contains__(')') and  not re.search('[a-zA-Z]', refline)):
              refline = line[line.find('(')+1:line.find(')')]
              if not re.search('[a-zA-Z]', refline):
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `^`, `$` is whats preventing you from getting all the numbers. And `gm` flags wont work in python `re`.

You can change your regex to :`([1-9][0-9]*|\([1-9][0-9]*\}|\(?:([1-9][0-9]*,?)+[1-9][0-9]*\))` if you want to get each number separately.

Or you can simplify your pattern to `(?<=[(,])[1-9][0-9]+(?=[,)])`
Test regex here: https://regex101.com/r/RlGwve/1

Python code:

```py
import re

line = """
Abuta has a history of use in the preparation of curares, an arrow poison to cause asphyxiation in hunting
It has also been used in traditional South American and Indian Ayurvedic medicines (101065,101066,101067)
The genus name Cissampelos is derived from the Greek words for ivy and vine (101065)
"""
print(re.findall(r'(?<=[(,])[1-9][0-9]+(?=[,)])', line))
# ['101065', '101066', '101067', '101065']
```

```
(?<=[(,])[1-9][0-9]+(?=[,)])
```

The above pattern tells to match numbers which begin with 1-9 followed by one or more digits, only if the numbers begin with or end with either comma or brackets.

Comment: Wouldn't that also match a bit if there where a `13,14,45` without any parenthesis in the text? (Not sure if that can happen.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\()[1-9]+\d*(?:,[1-9]\d*)*(?=\))")
results = [match[0].split(",") for match in pattern.finditer(line)]
```

- `(?<=\()`: Lookbehind for `(`
- `[1-9]+\d*`: At least one number (would `\d+` work too?)
- `(?:,[1-9]\d*)*`: Zero or multiple numbers after a `,`
- `(?=\))`: Lookahead for `)`

Result for your `line`:

```
[['101065', '101066', '101067'], ['101065']]
```

If you only want the comma separated numbers:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\()[1-9]+\d*(?:,[1-9]\d*)+(?=\))")
results = [match[0].split(",") for match in pattern.finditer(line)]
```

- `(?:,[1-9]\d*)+`: *One* or more numbers after a `,`

Result:

```
[['101065', '101066', '101067']]
```

Now, if your line could also look like

```
line = """
Abuta has a history of use in the preparation of curares, an arrow poison to cause asphyxiation in hunting
It has also been used in traditional South American and Indian Ayurvedic medicines ( 101065,101066,   101067 )
The genus name Cissampelos is derived from the Greek words for ivy and vine (101065)
"""
```

then you have to sprinkle the `pattern` with `\s*` and remove the whitespace afterwards (here with [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)):

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=\()\s*[1-9]+\d*(?:\s*,\s*[1-9]\d*\s*)*(?=\))")
table = str.maketrans("", "", " ")
results = [match[0].translate(table).split(",") for match in pattern.finditer(line)]
```

Result:

```
[['101065', '101066', '101067'], ['101065']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [pypi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) you could also use capture groups:

```
\((?P<num>\d+)(?:,(?P<num>\d+))*\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?P<num>\d+)` Capture group, match 1+ digits
- `(?:,(?P<num>\d+))*` Optionally repeat matching `,` and 1+ digits in a capture group
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V0RME6/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##TVFNaxtBDL3PrxB72mmXEFOaQqgTTA4ht0BzNBRlV/aKej7QaJzsr3c0tg@dgzSDpPf03uRF5xR/nE4cchIFoT19OpdRlSTCGqTb9v3j6@9Yw8N2@u77x/vh/7f/tvWdcweOZN1d17nNe1WEGQtY5KJJFkg7qIWAI@hMkIUyCiqn2CpjFRQqA2AEFEkfkBMXq2mCEdscljwvn3yZMJC5RuW4dy964TmUBO9EsZFMZxbBiVs3HuBPqjrDJpDw2BjiBC9xYrtulipHmniE0KJJKNCvble3dz@Hc7q7pF/evdnae4q1QMRA8MSlYMh0SAW4wGTYBgQ7SeGs8FmI/sFHkqnALgnwcTkTH5tNVwrvmlsuoI6zEa8v3t/s2JYz8/vrHwzQvPXONZy/A4SmzzYxPajUX8cHKIqi65W/d2AnC0ftw82IWauZa/K0996dTl8)

**Example code**

```
import regex

pattern = r"\((?P<num>\d+)(?:,(?P<num>\d+))*\)"

line = """
Abuta has a history of use in the preparation of curares, an arrow poison to cause asphyxiation in hunting
It has also been used in traditional South American and Indian Ayurvedic medicines (101065,101066,101067)
The genus name Cissampelos is derived from the Greek words for ivy and vine (101065)
"""

matches = regex.finditer(pattern, line)

for _, m in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print(m.capturesdict())
```

**Output**

```
{'num': ['101065', '101066', '101067']}
{'num': ['101065']}
```